# CSV Handling / FileReader and BufferedReader with UTF-8

Tags: java, arrays, csv, utf-8

I am having issues with reading a csv file and `UTF-8.` What I am doing is, reading the file to a `String Array`. Converting the `String Array` to a `2D String Array`, depending on the line separator. Cleaning the line separator and displaying the 2D `String Array` in the console.

The issue is, that special characters like `ö` and `ä` are messed up on the console.

`System.out.println("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());`

Tells me that my system is using `UTF-8`. What am I doing wrong?

I´m handling the CSV files with a `2D Array` to get direct access to the rows and columns. Is there a better approach for that?

```
// Reading File
public static String[] readFile(String path) throws IOException {
    FileReader input = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(input);

    String[] stringBuff = new String[countLines(path)];
    int lines = countLines(path);

    for (int j = 0; j < lines; j++) {
        stringBuff[j] = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
    return stringBuff;
}

// Converting to a 2D Array
public static String[][] convert(String[] array, String path) throws IOException {
    int lines = countLines(path);
    int[] locationarray;
    int columns = (findcolumn(array)) + 1;
    String[][] array2 = new String[lines][columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        locationarray = findlocation(array, i);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array2[i][j] = array[i].substring(locationarray[j], locationarray[j + 1]);
            array2[i][j] = cleanup(array2[i][j]);
            // System.out.print(array2[i][j]);
        }
        // System.out.println();
    }
    return array2;
}

// Show Array
public static void showarray(String[][] srcfinal) {
    for (int i = 0; i < srcfinal.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < srcfinal[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.print(srcfinal[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```